# Исчезающий блок при hover

Tags: html, css, hover

На http://www.lesha.wemakesites.ru/ есть макет страницы. Нужно, чтобы при наведении на кружок вместо него появлялась кнопка follow me, а сейчас она появляется вместе с ним. Как сделать так, чтобы при hover иконка заменялась кнопкой?

Comment: .button:hover { display: none; }

Comment: @MedvedevDev обновил страницу на хосте, не помогло.

Comment: естественно не помогло. при ховере кнопка скрывается и снова появляется, потому что ховерить уже не на что

Comment: Ну, речи и не шло о том, что бы не пропадал) Конечно же логичнее сделать общий контейнер и плясать от ховера по этому контейнеру, а не по кнопкам ...

Comment: @MedvedevDev спасибо!

Comment: @MedvedevDev а как теперь изменить кнопку при нажатии на неё?
пишу
   .block:focus .button-2 {
    background: olive;
}
не помогает

Comment: @lesha_ber, тут уже без js не обойтись, фокус будут получать только кнопки всегда, но если вы зададите стиль через .button-2:focus, то задать его же для .button-1 не получится, так как он стоит перед .button-1

Comment: @MedvedevDev понял, буду пробовать)

Answer (score 1):

```css
.block {
  display: inline-block;
}

.button-2 {
  display: none;
}

.block:hover .button-1 {
  display: none;
}

.block:hover .button-2 {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <button class="button-1">+</button>
  <button class="button-2">Follow me</button>
</div>
```